# Commits on master not on develop

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have the below scenario in my BitBucket:

[image: Commits on master not on develop]

and 3 commits on develop not on Master

How can I get them in sync?

While I can merge the 3 commits on develop onto Master, how do I resolve the issue where commits on master not on develop, when I check the commits, they are no other differences other than just the commits itself.

They are just a bunch of "Merged in develop"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `develop` is your default branch and `master` is `2 commits behind, 23 commits ahead develop`.

Pull `develop` branch into `master` and vice versa. Then Push both branches to sync them.

```
$ git fetch
$ git checkout master
$ git pull origin develop       # pull develop into master
$ git push origin master        # update remote/master 

$ git checkout develop    
$ git pull origin master        # pull master into develop
$ git push origin develop       # update remote/develop
```